# Spring Framework - Translation not working when sending e-mail in asynchronous thread

Tags: email, spring-mvc, asynchronous, freemarker, resourcebundle

I'm creating an application with Spring MVC (4.3.6).
This application has a functionality to send an e-mail after the user completes the registration process.
Freemarker (2.3.23) is used to define the e-mail text with spring.ftl template. The application accepts two languages - Portuguese and English.
We have choosen to use just one freemarker template and regarding the current language we use a ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource object from Spring context to get texts from internationalized ".properties" files.
The application sends the e-mail in an asynchronous thread using @Async annotation from Spring.
Actually when we send the e-mail asynchronously it's always translated to english. However when the e-mail is sent in a synchronous thread it's translated to the correct language.
It seems ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource is not available when we use asynchronous thread so the default languase is used.
I spent some time doing researches over the internet but I didn't find a solution for the problem.

Below the ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource config:

```
@Bean()
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource(){
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:resource-bundle");
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

Thread pool configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
}

@Override
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
}
```

Below the methods that are used to send the e-mail:

```
@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
@Override
public void sendRegistrationEmail(final Account user, final HttpServletRequest request, final Locale locale) {
    final String registrationTemplate = "fm_registrationConfirmation.ftl";
    MimeMessagePreparator mimeMessagePreparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
        @Override
        public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
            helper.setSubject(messageSource.getMessage("account.activation.email.message.subject", null, locale));
            helper.setFrom(emailDomainProperties.getFrom());
            helper.setTo(user.getEmail());

            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();

            model.put("springMacroRequestContext", new RequestContext(request, null, null, null));              

            model.put("account", user);
            model.put("locale", locale);
            model.put("bundle", messageSource);
            helper.setText(getFreeMarkerTemplateContent(model, registrationTemplate), true);
        }
    };
    this.javaMailSender.send(mimeMessagePreparator);
}

private String getFreeMarkerTemplateContent(Map<String, Object> model, final String template){
    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
    try{
     content.append(FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString( 
             freeMarkerConfiguration.getTemplate(template),model));
     return content.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception occured while processing " + template + ":"+e.getMessage());
    }
    return "";
}
```

And my freemarker template:

<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring />

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <@spring.message "account.activation.email.message.greeting" />

    <h3>${account.firstName}</h3>

    <p><@spring.message "account.activation.email.message.click" /></p>

    <a href="http://localhost:8080/smartNews/account/activateAccount/${account.id}?language=${locale}" target="_blank">http://localhost:8080/smartNews/account/activateAccount/${account.id}?language=${locale}</a>
</body>
```

Comment: This sounds like you can try to configure `LocaleContextHolder` and enable `inheritable` flag: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html

Comment: To configure LocaleContextHolder I used the code "  LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(LocaleContextHolder.getLocale(), true);
" in my AbstractController constructor but it didn't work.